# Xampp, Apache and SSH tunneling

Tags: apache, ssh, xampp, tunnel

I'm developing a PHP application on my localhost (Windows) using Xampp. I need to access a third party API from my application but I only have access to the API using our online server IP address.
How can I re-route my Apache requests to internet thru our online server using SSH tunnel?
(I can't setup a VPN connection)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your the URL for your third party API is at:

```
192.168.200.100 on port 80
```

And your online server IP is:

```
10.10.10.100
```

To open the tunnel run the following command:

```
ssh -L127.0.0.1:8888:192.168.200.100:80 10.10.10.100
```

The ssh command will manually connect you to your online server and open an SSH tunnel that you can reference at:

```
127.0.0.1 on port 8888
```

So in your PHP application instead of connecting directly to the third party server at 192.168.200.100, you use your local IP and port (127.0.0.1:8888) instead.

Comment: The api address is http://test.com/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL and i'm trying to connect to it using Nusoap. I tried your command using Putty: ssh -L127.0.0.1:8888:test.com:80 myserverip but it didn't work. any idea? Thanks

Comment: What exactly didn't work?  The ssh command didn't work or your code is still unable to connect?  Remember that in your php code you need to reference the api address as 127.0.0.1:8888/ws/ReferencePayment?wsdl

Comment: I log in to the server using Putty with my root user, then type your command. Now when I type in 127.0.0.1:8888/ws/ReferencePayment?wsdl in my browser or use it in my script, I can't reach the API website.

Comment: So i guess The ssh command works but the code is still unable to connect.

Comment: Is test.com the actual server or just a bogus name you use instead of the actual server name on this post?  Reason I ask is because it's just a domain name.  It should be something like www.test.com.  Just making sure we're not overlooking something and that you're actually connecting to the server.  Run nslookup command on the server name and try it with the IP address and re-do the ssh tunnel using IP.

Comment: Its just a bogus name, I tried the command with IP address of API server and it's still not working. tried http://127.0.0.1:8888/ on my browser and got connection error.

Comment: Okay are sure you can call the third party api from your server that we're building the SSH tunnel to?  To test that I would log into your other server and run the command "telnet test.com 80".  If the connectivity is working you should be able to enter basic HTTP GET command ie. GET /ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL.